# Sentence Transformers can not get a lot of images' embeddings

Tags: python, pytorch, bert-language-model, sentence-transformers

When I try to get embeddings from images I get error like this 'too many open files'. I have 50000 images, I do not want to split images into different folders and then concatenate embeddings (It is possible decision), I want to get embdedding using one folder where I have 50000 images. How to solve this problem?

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer, util
from PIL import Image

#Load CLIP model
model = SentenceTransformer('clip-ViT-B-32')

#Encode an image:
img_emb = model.encode([Image.open(filepath) for filepath in image_names], batch_size=128, convert_to_tensor=True, show_progress_bar=True)
```